# In the running vs in training

Tags: articles, usage

First, I want to confirm the grammatical correctness of the following two sentences:

> 1. I'm in the running for the position.
> 2. I'm in training for the position.

In other words, if using the word running is it right to put the article before it and if the word training is used is it right to not put the article before it?  And, if both are correct, what is the grammatical rule that governs when to use the article and when to leave it out?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real grammatical rule involved here. Both "in the running" and "in training" are simply idioms.

Comment: And both can be found in dictionaries https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20running (scroll down), https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20training

Answer (score 0):

to be **in the running** means: **you are being considered for the position**

to be **in training** means you are training for it.

Those are the way those are said.